# Linux: Is there a way to timestamp all output bring printed to the monitor?

Tags: linux, console, timestamp

Is there a way to add a timestamp to everything that gets printed to the monitor for Linux? I'm running CentOS 6.5 and 7 for reference. For example, here is a sample output:

```
SELinux:  Initializing.
Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
Initializing cgroup subsys ns
```

I'd like it to show up as:

```
1494019853 SELinux:  Initializing.
1494019853 Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
1494019854 Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
1494019854 Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
1494019857 Initializing cgroup subsys ns
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to prepend a timestamp to the results of a command/script, using `ts` from the `moreutils` package:

```
echo 'Hello world!' | ts "%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S"
```

Output:

```
05/05/2017_14:55:33 Hello world!
```

You can install the package `moreutils` (if available from your repository) with:

```
apt-get-update && apt-get install moreutils
```

**Edit**: If you want to print a timestamp on ALL system messages appearing on the terminal, I wouldn't know how to do this. However, you could still be able to check the timestamp for many of those messages on system logs, which store messages with a timestamp. Here are some of those logs (note that the path may be different on your system):

**1)** **/var/log/messages**, **/var/log/syslog**: those logs have human readable timestamps.

**2)**  **dmesg**:  to examine the `dmesg` log with readable timestamps, you could use the following command:

`dmesg -T`

Sample output:

```
[Mon May  8 11:53:59 2017] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[Mon May  8 11:53:59 2017] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I more meant prepending a time to messages that the system prints out. For example, when Linux boots up for the first time, I'd like to prepend timestamps to those messages, as well as any other messages the system prints after booting.

Comment: I see. I don't know how to do this -- it is probably not easy, because those messages can came from many different parts of the system. However, I added an imperfect workaround to my answer, which may or may not help you, check it out.

Comment: dmesg -T is helpful and pretty close to what I'm looking for, but only looks to be available in CentOS 7. 6.5 doesn't what the timestamp capability for dmesg even after updating util-linux-ng.